# Bulk insert with variable date field for non existing dates?

Tags: t-sql

```
Attendence
(
  Stu_id int
  Att_Id int
  Att_Date datetime
  Att_Num numeric(15,5)
)
```

This table basically contains attendence records.  I am trying to find the logic to enter the rows for missing dates from 1 Jan 2012 till today.

Assume there is a single attendence record for this period `row (1,1,'2012-05-06',1.20000)`. Then I would like to insert rows for each day from 1 Jan 2012 till today except the existing date with the same values for all the fields except the date field which should be the actual date.

I am trying to bulk insert all the rows but don't know how would I adjust the date field 
and check for the existing date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a stored procedure which loops through the dates.

Or better yet, make a dates table and select from that. This will be *much* faster. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Attendence (Stu_id, Att_Id, Att_Date, Att_Num)
SELECT a.Stu_id, a.Att_Id, d.TheDate, a.Att_Num
FROM Attendence a
INNER JOIN Dates d ON d.TheDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
    AND d.TheDate <> a.Att_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DateDiff function to figure out the amount of days inbetween the date in the function and the date in question. Make a DateTime variable and give it the value of 1 Jan 2012. Then set up a while loop that loops the amount of days from the DateDiff function.

In psuedo, the while loop would look something like this.

```
@DaysTill = DateDiff(days, 1/1/2012, @SomeDate)
While @DaysTill>0
    @@Check = Select Count(Att_Date) From Attendance where AttDate = DateAdd(days, @DaysTill, Jan 1st 2012)
    IF @@Check = 0 THEN Insert Into Attendance VALUES @Stu, @Id, DateAdd(days, @DaysTill, Jan 1st 2012), @numeric
    @DaysTill = @DaysTill - 1
END
```

The main things are understanding DateAdd and DateDiff. After that everything becomes relatively simple.